# Is there a way to replace all intstances of a string but only when it is contained in html tags shown to the user with javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

For example, if i wanted to replace "mystring" with "myotherstring" in

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="mystring">mystring</h1>
<p>mystring</p>
<script>mystring javascript blah</script>
</body>
</html>
```

how could i only replace it in the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags with javascript, or can i do it without js?

Comment: Why are you treating HTML as text? HTML is parsed by browsers, you don't need to parse it youtself

Comment: A way to do this is to use regex. So you can tell you only replace mystring when it's circled with > and <

Comment: @Guillaume rethink your suggestion. You should **never use regular expressions to parse HTML**, rather a proper inbuilt [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/383904)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You're right, my approach expected this html to be a whole text to be converted uing JS

Comment: @Guillaume that's not *any kind of text*. It's HTML, where it's absolutely normal to have i.e: stuff like: `<p data-p="<p>mystring</p>">mystring</p>` or stull like `<script>//this creates <p>mystring</p>` etc etc etc. Regex is just not suited for the job.

Comment: @Christian Vincenzo TrainaI wouldn't if I didn't have to, but in this case I don't have control over the actual html so i want to change the string

Comment: @Fexo you accepted Jamie answer, that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the specific tags you're interested in and do the replacement.

```
document.querySelectorAll("h1, p").forEach((el) => {
      el.textContent = el.textContent.replace(/\bmystring\b/g, "myotherstring");
    });
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-firefly-ssb8cj?file=/src/index.js
Read more about the [`\b` (Word Boundary)](https://javascript.info/regexp-boundary)

Comment: Good call. Updated the code snippet